Inside pdb just before executing a Python script, can you set up your own sys.audit() hook?
Just before running a Python script inside pdb (using python -m pdb), I tried to add a handler for sys.audit() calls:
interact     ← puts pdb into interactive Python mode
import sys
def myaudit(event, args):
    print(f'audit: {event} with args={args}')
sys.addaudithook(myaudit)
ctrl-D       ← exits pdb’s interactive Python mode

Unfortunately, this yields:
... sys.addaudithook(myaudit)
  File "<console>", line 3
    sys.addaudithook(myaudit)
    ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What am I missing?

You need to enter a blank line after the end of the function definition, so the interpreter knows you're done with the function:
interact
import sys
def myaudit(event, args):
    print(f'audit: {event} with args={args}')

sys.addaudithook(myaudit)
ctrl-D

